# TypeScript - possibly undefined compilation error when throwing by iterator

Tags: typescript, iterator, undefined, generator, throw

I'm keeping on the train the ts with generators when that annoying transpiler behaviour occurred. Of course, I use --strictNullChecks

```
function* generat(end: number) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= end; i++) {
    try {
      yield i;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}

let iterat = generat(5);

console.log(iterat.next());
console.log(iterat.next());
console.log(iterat.throw()); // error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
console.log(iterat.next());
console.log(iterat.next());
console.log(iterat.next());
```

Anybody know a smart solution? I mean smart by something different than in this link: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14431

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, [`throw` and `return` are both optional in Iterator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html).

```
interface Iterator<T> {
  next(value?: any): IteratorResult<T>;
  return?(value?: any): IteratorResult<T>;
  throw?(e?: any): IteratorResult<T>;
}
```

Honestly, I don't understand why generators have to return Iterators instead of something more specific. After all, GeneratorFunctions always return something and they always can error out. [I filed a suggestion  for `TypeScript` here.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21527)

In the meantime, you can get around this by doing:

```
iterat.throw!()
```